# Why does my mouse sensitivity spontaneously change?

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

Sometimes when I'm playing, my mouse sensitivity will spontaneously change for no reason. Any thoughts on what can cause this?

Comment: I should note this only happens when I play League, and even then somewhat rarely. Its a bitch when it happens however, as I have to open my league options and re-adjust my sensitivity rather than spend the time farming, killing, ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug that Riot is working to fix (click the Riot logo next to "First Riot Post" in this link):

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2721861

A few people have reported it fixed as of the last patch, so chime in on that forum post if you're still having trouble after patching!  And make sure to submit your logs any game the sensitivity bug occurs.